# How to login to Facebook account other than the developer's account using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I am a beginner in android and I am trying to make a simple application on android that implements Facbook SDK to login into Facebook. After application launched, it shows the facebook login page. When I insert my fb id and password into that form it logins successfully to my app, but when I try to login with any other id instead of my id it shows the following error on the emulator.

*App not setup: the developers of this app have not setup this app properly for facbook login ok

Comment: You need to add facebook login instruments in your code

Comment: how? i have no idea about it

Comment: try this http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/android-facebook-login-example/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Login to your facebook developer account ,
2. Go to the settings of your app.
3. There is an option as "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"
4. Switch that into "YES"and try again.

Comment: Until the facebook app is published, only the developer can use it during development.